# I duplicate a file in photos app mac and it references the same file

Tags: photos

I duplicate a file in photos app for mac and it references the same file rather than export a new file. I use a referenced library.

Answer (score 1):

Duplicating it simply duplicates the pointer within the library, it does not actually duplicate the underlying file. This occurs whether or not you have a referenced library. You can test this by using the Edit tools to make a change - such as cropping - then duplicating the image. The duplicated image has a "Revert to Original" button in Edit mode that takes you back to what the image looked like before the change, even though this "duplicate" image didn't even exist at that point in time.

Based on this, it appears the duplicate function is intended to allow you to maintain multiple versions of an image at the same time, but still allow you to do so non-destructively.

If you want to physically duplicate the file, you need to do so in Finder and then import that file into Photos.

@Tetsujin is correct about the hard link.

Comment: Great info. Appreciate the responses from @Tetsujin and yourself.

Comment: This was my first question and I am impressed by all the assistance.

Comment: @Ross I'm glad we could help. Ask Different works by a user accepting the post that answers their question - simply click the check mark next to the question. In addition, clicking the up arrow next to the post up votes it, which the system uses to determine the best answers in the case of multiple answers.

Answer (score 0):

I think the trick is to drag a copy out to the desktop, otherwise it will make a hard link rather than a copy.

Comment: Hmmm... will have to investigate later, on phone right now.

Comment: I can't repro that. Option/drag a photo straight from Photos to the desktop. Edit the one still in Photos in some obvious way. Change the name of the one on the desktop. Drag to the Photos icon in the Dock. Compare.